# Do i need to put path params in an URI if i don't use them [REST APIs]

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm having a debate with a senior of mine at work and i want to know if what he says is true. Imagine I have a path `/users/bucket-list` that gets the currently logged in user bucket list. Now my question is, since i get the ID of the logged in user from the context do i still need to name my path like this `/users/:user_id/bucket-list`. I don't use the path param but my senior thinks that it should still be there and I think that since i don't use it i need to omit it. I want to hear your thoughts about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR

- You are "doing it wrong"

  - Most of the time, you'll get away with it

    - Getting away with it is the wrong goal

---

> Any information that can be named can be a resource -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

In most cases, I find that the easiest way to reason about "resources" is to substitute "documents", and then once the basic ideas are in place to then generalize if necessary.

One of the design problems that we face in creating our API is figuring out our resources; should "Alice's bucket-list" be presented separately from "Bob's bucket-list", or do they belong together?  Do we have one resource for the entire list, or one resource for each entry in the list, and so on.

A related problem we need to consider in our design is how many representations a resource should support.  This might include choosing to support multiple file formats (csv vs plain-text vs json, etc), and different languages (EN vs FR), and so on.

Your senior's proposed design is analogous to having two different resources.  And having done that, everything will Just Work[tm].  There's no confusion about which resource is being identified, authorization is completely separate from identification, and so on.

Your design, however, is analogous to having a single resource with multiple representations, where a representation is chosen based on who is looking at it.  And that's kind of a mess -- certainly your server can interpret the HTTP request, but general purpose components are not going to know that your resource has different identification semantics than every other resource on the internet.

We normally discriminate different representations using the Vary header; but the Authorization field is sort of out of bounds there, see [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4).

In practice, you are likely to get away with your design because we have special rules about how shared-caches interact with authenticated requests, see [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3.2).

But "likely to get away with it" is pretty weak.  The point of having common standards is to get interop.  If you are going to risk interop, you had better be getting something very valuable back in exchange.  Nothing you have presented here suggests a compensating advantage.